# Difference between executing script on 'changeInfo.status = loading' and 'changeInfo.status = completed'

Tags: google-chrome-extension

What difference does it make on executing script when

```
changeInfo.status = loading vs changeInfo.status == 'completed' in chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener?
```

Because when we execute a script when the status is loading the injected script intercepts fetch calls while it doesn't on status completed.

Any help?

details : we are trying to intercept fetch call of a website through the injected script injected on chrome.tabes.onUpdated. The issue is when injected script is executed when `changeInfo.status = complete`,inject script cannot intercept fetch calls..but if the injected script is executed on `changeInfo.status = loading` it intercepts the fetch calls. Why does this happen was my question?

Comment: Seems self-explanatory but I'll try: `loading` means the page only starts loading so none of its scripts has run yet (if you inject here your code will be able to "see" what the page scripts do) whereas `complete` means the page has already loaded and its initial scripts has already run.

Comment: and the fetch calls have meta data headers to make them more secure..so any chances that on loading our inject script is already executed even before the fetch metadata header are attached to fetch request..while on completed the metadata headers are already attached to fetch request and hence they stop inject script from intercepting..

Comment: this is my analysis but note sure..hence i need help to confirm this..thanks

Comment: Note that it's still unclear what the problem is. You may need to add [MCVE](/help/mcve) (code).

Comment: problem is when i execute inject script on changeInfo.status = complete,the fetch calls are not intercepted

Comment: You've repeated the question but it's unclear why you want to use `complete` if it's already established that it doesn't work because it runs too late.

Comment: can we have a chat rather than comments?.

Comment: It's best to provide the info in the question.

Comment: I wanted to understand why is that when we execute inject script on changeInfo.status = complete does not intercept the fetch calls while it does intercept when executed on change.Info.status = loading

Comment: I think this is what my first comment explained.